# Shared library failure while deploying on Sony SmallAppSample on Device

Tags: android, sony

I tired to run Sony SmallAppSample (Smartwatch2) from eclipse. It works fine on emulator but when I try to deploy on device it fails with error:

12-22 15:50:37.248: E/PackageManager(761): Package com.sony.nfx.app.smallappsample requires unavailable shared library com.sony.smallapp.framework; failing!

I made sure in project properties, in "Java build path", "Order and export" tab, "Sony add-on SDK 2.1" is selected.

Any ideas how to include shared library/ fix the problem?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: No, I abandoned it. dev on sony sw2 is really hard. Hoping android wear sdk is better, haven't got my hands on it yet.